# Declare variable syntax error in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Declare variable syntax error in MySQL Workbench? the code is ok but the error is on DECLARE cod int;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertarPro(
   nom  varchar(100),
   pre  decimal(18, 2),
   img  varchar(100)
)

DECLARE cod int;
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(codigoProducto),0)+1 into cod FROM producto;
INSERT INTO producto VALUES (cod,nom,pre,img);
```

ERROR:

```
create procedure sp_insertarPro(nom  varchar(100),pre decimal(18, 2),img  varchar(100))  declare cod int    

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare cod int' at line 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this:

```
      DELIMITER $$
      CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertarPro(
        nom  varchar(100),
        pre  decimal(18, 2),
        img  varchar(100)
      )
      BEGIN
      DECLARE cod int;
      SELECT IFNULL(MAX(codigoProducto),0)+1 into cod FROM producto;
      INSERT INTO producto VALUES (cod,nom,pre,img);
      END $$
      DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks, boss it works, u save my life, five stars 4 u.

Comment: LOL ... I completely understand you. Some codes kill us lol. Happy to helo you. Mark as solved to help others. See you my friend!